# Tomcat always redirecting to error page

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, form-authentication

I'm developing a web application in Java using JSP and Servlets and I'm using Java Form Authentication to authenticate users.

Below is the web.xml configuration for login.

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/jsp/login.jsp?action=login</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/jsp/login.jsp?action=loginFailed</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

When I was developing in my machine, everything was fine. I then moved to test server with SSL enabled for the site. I was testing with https and everytime the `<form-error-page>` is called and the user is unable to login. Thought the LoginModule returns true, only the form-error-page is called.

**EDIT :**
The reason is not SSL because the same issue is reproduced in my local machine without HTTPS. **This occurs in Tomcat version 7.0.90 and does not occur in 7.0.78.**

What is the reason and how do I fix this?

Comment: Try this: Disable or remove error page. Then run it. Check what is the error.

Comment: @DeepakGautam I got "No error page was defined for FORM authentication in context []" error in my log and "This page is not working. HTTP Error 500" in my browser.

Comment: @SudharshRam If you are seeing an HTTP 500 error in the browser then there was a server error and there should be a stack trace in Tomcat's log. Can you update your post to show that stack trace?